# How to capitalize all 1st alphabet in the words in a string excluding some cases like 'by'?

Tags: javascript, capitalization

This is what I have done so far. I am capitalizing the first alphabet of all the words.

Expected output: **Dance by Cow**

Output I received was : **Dance By Cow**

```
let capitalize = str => {
   return str
     .toLowerCase()
     .split('-')
     .map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
     .join(' ');
};

toTitleCase('dance-by-cow');
```

Comment: So you need to alter your map code to look for words to not caps.... basic if statement....

Comment: What are "some cases"? These few million words in the english languge that are not nouns?

Comment: It's not really clear to me how this code is supposed to just know that `"by"` should be treated differently than any other word, so the expectation of output seems unwarranted. Where is the attempt at handling `"by"` differently here? There will need to be a conditional or data structure of some sort and which the `map` call can take into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
const stopwords = new Set (['by', 'with', 'to', 'from', 'and', 'the'])
```

Then...

```
.map(s => stopwords.has(s) ? s : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
```

At this level it's just conditional code. But, getting a correct set of stopwords isn't a trivial thing to do.

Comment: Woah, that's elegant! I like that.

Comment: When I try using this method, I still don't get my expected output.

```
let capitalize = str => {
  const stopwords = new Set ('by', 'with', 'to', 'from', 'and', 'the')
    return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .split('-')
      .map(s => stopwords.has(s) ? s : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
      .join(' ');
  };


capitalize('dance-by-cow')
```

Comment: You are right. the `Set()` constructor needs a list of words.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on the right track. Maybe one good solution is to create an exceptions array which contains the specific words what you would like to skip from converting the first char to uppercase.

Please find the extended solution:

```js
const toTitleCase = (value) => {
  const exceptions = ['by']; // handling the specific words
  const handleMapping = s => exceptions.includes(s) ? s : s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
  
  return value.toLowerCase()
    .split('-')
    .map(handleMapping)
    .join(' ');
}

console.log(toTitleCase('dance-by-cow'));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like using, using the second parameter to provide your exclusion words being as you don't specify any other ones in your post.

```js
function toTitleCase(input, exclusions = []) {
  return input
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('-')
    .map((word) => {
      return exclusions.includes(word) ? word : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    })
    .join(' ');
}

let example = toTitleCase('dance-by-cow', ['by']);

console.log(example);
```